# how to order an attribute with respect to other attributes?

Tags: java

I need to know how to order an attribute with respect to other attributes. for eg. if i have a class named fruit and it has attributes like name, price, color,count in stock etc. and it has been stored it in an array of objects.My doubt is how will it be able to arrange price of the fruit in an order(either ascending or descending) with respect to name and color of that fruit

Comment: This can be done if you define your custom comparator.

Comment: @kai, post your comment as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement `Comparable` in your class `Laptop`, and define the order in the compareTo method.

```
public class Laptop implements Comparable<Laptop>{

    public int compareTo(Laptop compareLaptop) {
        //logic here
    }
}
```

Then just call:

```
List<Laptop> laptops = new ArrayList<Laptop>();
Collections.sort(laptops);
```

Good tutorial: http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8 you can write

```
List<Laptop> sorted = laptops.stream()
       .sort(comparing(Laptop::getCapacity).reversed()
            .thenComparing(Laptop::getSpeed))
       .collect(toList()):
```